# Combinations: Please tell me where I went wrong

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have developed this doubt in several combination questions.  One such  question is as follows: A box contains two white balls, three black balls and four red balls. In how many ways can three balls be drawn from the box if at least one black ball is to be included in the draw?

My initial solution was something like this: The one necessary black ball can be selected in 3c1 ways. There are two more balls to be selected from remaining EIGHT balls. Since these can be of any colour, this can be done in 8c2 ways. By the fundamental principle of multiplication, these two are additive works (and functions) and should be multiplied to get the total number of ways, i.e,, the answer must be 3c1*8c2. But  this is wrong as there would be repeated combinations. I realized this only when I gave  arbitrary names to the various balls and trialed. Though I solved it by making a table of combinations, I don't understand why my solution is getting repeated combinations.

Could you explain whether this is a flaw or a limitation of the fundamental principle of multiplication, or a mistake that I don't see?

Comment: "*A box contains two white balls, three black balls and four red balls*"  When a problem starts out like this and gives no other information about the balls, we generally assume that the balls of the same color are identical.  There are in that case $3^3-1=27-1=26$ possible ways to draw three balls ignoring the requirement that at least one be black (*minus one since drawing three white balls is impossible*) and so $26-(2^3-1)=19$ ways with a black ball.

Comment: The related problem starting "*A box contains two numbered white balls, three numbered black balls and four numbered red balls*" we can then assume the balls of the same color are still distinct.  If we don't care about the order in which the balls are drawn, there are $\binom{9}{3}$ ways to draw three balls ignoring the requirement and $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to draw three balls without any black, giving $\binom{9}{3}-\binom{6}{3}$ total ways.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication principle applies (in the case of two choices) only if each set of two choices results in a distinct outcome (i.e., the function from sets of choices to outcomes is injective). For example, if you were counting the number of ways to pick one black ball and two red balls, you could multiply $\binom{3}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{2}$ because each choice of a specific black ball and a specific pair of red balls gives a different set of balls from a different choice of specific black ball and pair of red balls.

However, this is not the case in your example. Naming the black balls $A$, $B$, and $C$ (as you indicate you did), choosing $A$ and then choosing the pair $B,C$ gives the same outcome as choosing $C$ and then choosing the pair $A,B$. So the multiplication principle does not apply.

Comment: That example made it pretty clear for me. But how do I INSTANTLY judge whether I could apply the multiplication principle to the problem or not?

Comment: @RayyanAsifKhan I don't have an easy answer to that one. With experience you'll learn to tell when the choice uniquely determines the outcome and when it doesn't. There are easier and harder cases: e.g., if you're choosing from two separate pools (like one choice from black balls and one choice from red balls) you can use the multliplication principle